# Best Way to Install LTSP on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, software-installation, ltsp

Upgrading my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS to 16.04 then 18.04 LTS left LTSP unable to boot clients.
I am using the traditional 2 NIC structure on 1404, with thin clients on a physically separate subnet, and their system in chroot. It uses isc-dhcp-server and tftpd-hpa.

Trying to debug my upgraded system (including switching to dnsmasq) I came across bugs which only seem to be fixed in versions of packages later than those in the bionic repos, with no backports, so I gave up on the upgrade route.

So is there a currently reliable way of installing LTSP on 1804?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should follow official guide on LTSP wiki - http://wiki.ltsp.org/wiki/Installation/Ubuntu and do not forget to add Greek PPA (`ppa:ts.sch.gr`).

I did not tried 2 NIC configuration yet, but 1 NIC with ProxyDHCP work as expected with Greek PPA.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks N0rbertI already tried it and it worked first time. Seems most LTSP activity is in the educational sector these days. We're not in education so I hadn't really looked at these before. We don't have any Greek connections either, so I looked at Debian Edu first - which might work but I didn't try it because it seems to be intended for large networks with multiple LTSP servers, and needs a special router. The Greek Schools PPA seems a simpler solution. I installed the 2 NIC + chroot setup, although they seem to allow for all the alternatives too. The PPA has a much newer version of LTSP than the Ubuntu 18.04 and Debian Stable repos and they seem to have squashed all the bugs I had before.