# Ubuntu for Education

Tags: server, education

We are new to Linux. We have a small charter school customer that is struggling with a lab solution and Ubuntu seems to be a good choice with a server and thin clients. I bought a used server and 5 Dell thin clients to put up a lab and test. I also downloaded Ubuntu server. Just need to know if I'm headed in the right direction and if anyone has any tips or ideas. All the students need is internet access(Maybe Chrome) and basic office programs. The immediate need is to get 15 up and going but the long range plan is for about 90. Please help!!

Jay

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Best Way to Install LTSP on Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1109669/best-way-to-install-ltsp-on-ubuntu-18-04) . You are on the right direction. All you need to is to install and configure LTSP server and thin or thick (with at least 2 Gb of RAM) clients.

Comment: This sort of thing is happening at thousands of universities across the globe, i.e., it shouldn't be a problem. You might take a look at the Edubuntu version (http://www.edubuntu.org/), then contact them via mailing list (https://www.edubuntu.org/community). I'm sure they can help you, too. BTW, I might be all wrong about this, but a server-client setup requires ethernet, not WiFi?

Comment: I think edubuntu is abandoned.

Comment: Edubuntu might be abandoned, but most of the programs are still available to install in Ubuntu.  They just packaged everything up neatly.