# Need help to set up PXE

Tags: boot, server, pxe

I am trying to find info on using ubuntu server as a PXE boot. So our Client that we are building machines for gave us their own ISO. the computers they give us already aotumatically go into a PXE boot. I am making a standalone server to be hooked up to a switch so we can load the ISO to mulitpale machines at once.  All the info i have found online is not up todate. How to i configure Ubuntu server to PXE boot the ISO file that i have ?

thak you

Comment: Which supported release of Ubuntu are you using? Read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting

Comment: Read `man systemd-dnsmasq dnsmasq`. `dnsmasq` handles DNS, DHCP and PXE (which is a subset of DHCP). How can we tell what you have read?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Best Way to Install LTSP on Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1109669/best-way-to-install-ltsp-on-ubuntu-18-04). I would suggest to install LTSP, it will provide more functionality. You can build your own system image with build tools and so on.